# How do I clone a repo from Sourcehut

Tags: git

I would like to clone this repo on Sourcehut: [https://builds.sr.ht/~vlnk/bookmarkt](https://builds.sr.ht/%7Evlnk/bookmarkt) but I can't work out how. I have tried `git clone https://builds.sr.ht/~vlnk/bookmarkt` and doing web searches for instructions but I can't find anything.

Comment: https://builds.sr.ht/%7Evlnk/bookmarkt doesn't look like a repo? What about using https://git.sr.ht/~vlnk/bookmarkt instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https is needed , use git.sr.ht instead of builds.sr.ht:

```
git clone https://git.sr.ht/~vlnk/bookmarkt
```

Answer (score 0):

As per evolutionxbox's comment to clone from sourcehut the correct url form is `git clone https://git.sr.ht/~vlnk/bookmarkt`